# Using TFTPY in python causing time out

Tags: python, linux, networking, tftp

I was trying to transfer a log file using tftp. For client side I am using TFTPY module in python. But it is showing below mentioned error messages.

```
WARNING:tftpy:Timeout waiting for traffic, retrying...
ERROR:tftpy:Timed-out waiting for traffic
WARNING:tftpy:resending last packet
WARNING:tftpy:Resending packet RRQ packet: filename = /opt/TDK/logs//55194186195512_Console.log mode = octet on sessions <tftpy.TftpStates.TftpStateSentRRQ object at 0xb70a0f8c>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "callConsoleLogTransfer.py", line 30, in <module>
  consoleLogTransfer(IP,Port,logTransferPort,fileName,localFilePath)
  File "/file/consoleLogTransfer.py", line 68, in consoleLogTransfer
  client.download( remoteFile, localFile, timeout=20 )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftpy/TftpClient.py", line 52, in download
  self.context.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftpy/TftpContexts.py", line 378, in start
    self.state.resendLast()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tftpy/TftpStates.py", line 203, in resendLast
(self.context.host, self.context.tidport))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: probably port should be an integer number

Comment: I am giving port as an integer only